# reversing particular strings in sentence

Tags: python

I don't understand where I went wrong

> Write a function that takes in a string of one or more words, and returns the same string, but with all five or more letter words reversed (Just like the name of this Kata). Strings passed in will consist of only letters and spaces. Spaces will be included only when more than one word is present.

Examples:

```
>>> spinWords( "Hey fellow warriors" )
"Hey wollef sroirraw"
>>> spinWords( "This is a test")
"This is a test"
>>> spinWords( "This is another test" )
"This is rehtona test"
```

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    split_sentence = sentence.split(" ")
    new_sentence = ""
    for i in split_sentence:
        if len(i) >= 5:
            new_sentence += (i[::-1])
        else:
            new_sentence += i
        if split_sentence.index(i) + 1 < len(split_sentence):
            new_sentence += " "
    return new_sentence

print(spin_words("only sgnirtS rettel the sgnirtS will desrever or a but only will "))
```

This is my solution, but codewars sometimes says that I failed to pass the test and gives this as a reason.

`'etirW gnirts sgnirtS a secapS but sdrow secaps secaps etirW a word this but tsisnoc noitcnuf the desrever snruter sekat same name this rettel this or more more '` should equal `'etirW gnirts sgnirtS a secapS but sdrow secaps secaps etirW a word this but tsisnoc noitcnuf the desrever snruter sekat same name this rettel this or more more'`

Comment: What are the constraints for the input? Does it allow an empty string? A string with just spaces? A string with two spaces side by side? A space at the end of the string?

Comment: I have pasted the information that I was given above. "Write a function that takes in a string of one or more words, and returns the same string, but with all five or more letter words reversed (Just like the name of this Kata). Strings passed in will consist of only letters and spaces. Spaces will be included only when more than one word is present.

Examples: spinWords( "Hey fellow warriors" ) => returns "Hey wollef sroirraw" spinWords( "This is a test") => returns "This is a test" spinWords( "This is another test" )=> returns "This is rehtona test"
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for adding spaces is wrong:

```
split_sentence.index(i) + 1 < len(split_sentence)
```

`list.index()` gives the **first occurrence** of the word, so if the word appears more than once, it will be true when it shouldn't.

Don't manually join on spaces. Use `' '.join()` instead.

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    split_sentence = sentence.split(" ")
    new_words = []
    for word in split_sentence:
        if len(word) >= 5:
            new_words.append(word[::-1])
        else:
            new_words.append(word)
    return ' '.join(new_words)
```

Though FWIW I would use a comprehension:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    new_words = [w[::-1] if len(w) >= 5 else w for w in words]
    return ' '.join(new_words)
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked and I totally understand it now

Answer (score 0):

> 'etirW gnirts sgnirtS a secapS but sdrow secaps secaps etirW a word this but tsisnoc noitcnuf the desrever snruter sekat same name this rettel this or more more ' should equal 'etirW gnirts sgnirtS a secapS but sdrow secaps secaps etirW a word this but tsisnoc noitcnuf the desrever snruter sekat same name this rettel this or more more'

It tell you that you add one extra space at end of sentence. The way you insert the space is wrong. If more spaces at beginning, ending or between words, all got failed result.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
  def spinwords(inp):
    l1 = []
    a=inp.split(' ')
    b=''
    for i in a:
        if len(i)>4:
            i=i[::-1]
            b+=i+" "
        else:
            b+=i+" "
    return b
user = input('Say a phrase:')
print(spinwords(user))
```

the `i[::-1]` reverses the string.

output:

```
Say a phrase:I love stackoverflow
I love wolfrevokcats
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This has the exact same issue as the OP code: trailing space

Comment: he says that only words with length 5 or more will be reversed

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to be clear then edited my comment. Your code joins on spaces **unconditionally**, which is not what OP needs. For example `spinwords('hello')` -> `'hello '`. As well, `l1` is unused, `> 5` is wrong - should be `>= 5`, and you should return instead of printing.